# How to access ccnet page form different computer

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

ok so i can access the dash board from the server by going to http://localhost/ccnet

what i need to do is to be able to view this page from another computer but typing that url in the browser. if any one knows how to do this please help
thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put instead your localhost the IP address of server where you have ccnet
for example it would look something like this: http://192.168.1.66/ccnet
Of course I typed some default IP you need to check what's yours.
Also check if firewall is not blocking access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the server name to connect.  http://ServerName/ccnet.